# Пока не выполнится метод onActivityResult, предыдущее активити не отображается на экране.

Tags: android, java

По кнопке запускается проводник, где выбирается файл и получаем строку с путем к файлу, строка с путем к файлу передается в первое активити методом `onActivityResult`: в этом методе получаю строку с адресом файла, а далее вызываю метод по загрузке, дешифровке, сохранении и отображении файла. Пока все эти блоки выполняются, прежнее активити не отображается на экране.

```
// Открываем проводник
private void openConductor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenFile.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  
}

// Передаем строку с путем к файлу  в первое активити № 2
{
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("filename", filename);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
}
 // Получаем строку с путем к файлу в первом активити и вызываем метод load(FILENAME); 
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String filename = data.getStringExtra("filename");  
        FILENAME = filename;
        textadress.setText(FILENAME);
        load(FILENAME);

    }
}
```

Дак вот, пока метод `load(FILENAME)` не выполнится, а он может выполнятся очень долго
первое активити не отображается на экране, а может второе активити не закрывается
методом `finish();`.
Как сделать так, чтобы я получал строку с путем к файлу в первое активити, далее отображал само активити, а потом уже начинал работать со строкой с путем к файлу?
Надеюсь кто нибудь меня понял. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Надо не надеяться, чтобы кто-то понял, а учиться выражать свои мысли. Как минимум - может пригодится программисту.

Что вам мешает загружать файл в отдельном потоке?

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите `load(FILENAME)` в отдельный поток или `AsyncTask` (что в общем то параллельно). Пока файл грузится для разнообразия можно повесить `ProgressBar` (чтобы юзер не скучал)

Comment: Сделал все в AcyncTask и поставил ProgressDialog, но теперь новая проблема: скорость дешифровки упала, файл с 1200 символами раньше дешифрировал за 3 секунды, сейчас же на это уходит больше минуты! Можно ли как-нибудь увеличить приоритет потока?

Comment: А случайно прогресс на каждый символ не обновляете? Обновляйте раз на 100 символов - будет самое оно. А на каждый символ - нет смысла. Даже если Ваш прогресс длинной 600 пикселей, каждое второе обновление (при 1200 символах) будет ненужным.

Comment: Да стоял на каждый) поставил на 100, уже не минута, а 18 секунд. Спасибо!